# Moving Resources between subcriptions with AzureDevops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

Currently im trying to create dynamic environments via AzureDevops.

One of these steps to achieve this is to take a copy of our production databases and place them in a temp resource group (Production Subscription) and then move the sql server and associated databases to our non-production subscription. From here we then create the web apps and deploy code.

When i run this via Az Cli i am able to move the resources with the following

```
SQLSERVERID=$(az resource show -g $RSGNAMETEMP  -n $SQLSERVERNAME --resource-type "Microsoft.Sql/servers" --query id --output tsv)

az resource move --destination-group $RSGNAME --ids $SQLSERVERID --destination-subscription-id $SANDBOXSUBSCRIPTIONID
```

However when i run this via AzureDevops i get the following error

```
 ERROR: The client (...) with object id (...)  has permission to perform action  on scope  however, it does not have permission to perform action (...) on the linked scope(s).
```

I believe this problem is happening when you configure the AZ Cli step in AzureDevops you select the Subscription from the drop down list. The account / service principal only has access rights to that specific subscription and not to multiple.  Is it possible to configure a service principal (that can be used in AzureDevops) that can connect to multiple subscriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just go to Azure portal, navigate to the desired subscription blade, go to Access Control, press `+` sigh at the top and add your principal as a contributor to the subscription.

to find service principal name use this:

Click Manage link in the Azure Subscription field in your VSTS job, it will navigate you to a new blade. Click Manage Service Principal there. It will take you to the application page in Azure AD. After that you can copy name under Managed application in local directory field and use that name to grant it Key Vault permissions.

Comment: awesome that worked. can now move resources around subscriptions with ease